# How to getGroups() in keycloak using UserFederatedStorageProvider

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services, federated-storage-engine

I have created a User storage provider that connects with **keycloak** with an external DB and gets the Users & other related details successfully. In the same way, I am trying to get the groups associated with a particular user from external storage to populate them in the user groups page and mainly while token generation.

I have been trying to do this using the `getGroups()` method in UserFederatedStorageProvider but it doesn't get called anywhere from **keycloak** or even while token generation. I have deployed the **keycloak** in my local and have tested it. Attaching my code snippets for reference.

```java
    @Override
    public Set<GroupModel> getGroups(RealmModel realm, String userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet<GroupModel> testGroup = new HashSet<GroupModel>();
        logger.info("IN GET GROUPS ----------" + userId);
        GroupModel group1 = new Groups();
        group1.setName("testGroup1");
        testGroup.add(group1);
        return testGroup;
    }
```

I am using a UserStorageProviderFactory and then in my UserStorageProvider class I am implementing these for CRUD on Users and Credential handling. The one being implemented for groups is UserFederatedStorageProvider.

```java
public class StorageProvider implements UserStorageProvider, 
    UserLookupProvider, 
    UserRegistrationProvider,
    UserQueryProvider,
    UserFederatedStorageProvider,
    CredentialInputUpdater, 
    CredentialInputValidator {
```

Answer (score 0):

Although one year later, I had the exact same problem using `keycloak v18`. The solution: your overridden functions need to be in your `UserAdapter` class and not in the `UserFederatedStorageProvider`.

Of course your user adapter should extend the related class, eg:

`public class UserAdapter extends AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage`

This solved my problem!